# Slide panel upwards with jquery slideToggle

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I want to make a footer that is expandable when you click the '+' sign.. 
Initially, I have a very small footer with only copyright information and social media links. When the sign is clicked, I want a sitemap (and some other things) to slide above the copyright information.

However, I need to make sure that the page remains scrolled down entirely. If not, the panel will slide, but you won't be able to see it..

This is what I now have:

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer-wrapper" class="clearfix">
    <footer>
        <span id="footer-expander">+</span>
        <section id="footer-hidden" class="clearfix">
            <section id="sitemap" class="cols-3">
                <h1>Sitemap</h1>
                <ul>

                    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
            <section class="cols-3">
                <h1>Something else</h1>
            </section>
            <section class="cols-3">
                <h1>Last, but not least.</h1>
            </section>
        </section>
        <section id="footer-show" class="clearfix">
            <p>&copy; Helena Standaert.</p>
            <section id="btm-socialmedia" class="socialmedia">
                <ul>
                    <li class="twitter"><a href="">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li class="facebook"><a href="">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li class="linkedin"><a href="">LinkedIn</a></li>
                    <li class="rss"><a href="">RSS-feed</a></li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </section>
    </footer>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#footer-expander').click(function(){
    $('#footer-hidden').slideToggle('slow', function(){
        goToByScroll('footer-wrapper')
        if($('#footer-expander').html('-')){
            $('#footer-expander').html('+');
        }
        if($('#footer-expander').html('+')){
            $('#footer-expander').html('-');
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplefied, make a scroll interval which gets turned off by the scroll

```
var pageScroller = setInterval(function(){ 
                       scrollTo(0, document.scrollHeight)}, // Scroll to bottom
                       100 // every 100 ms correct. Can be 50, or 25, or whatever
                    );
$('#footer-hidden').slideToggle(600, function(){
    clearInterval( pageScroller ); // stop the interval which was scrolling
});
```

Comment: Thanks! However, I had to change the document.offsetHeight to document.body.scrollHeight, since the page would scroll to the top of the page.

Comment: Changed the solution :) Now other people can use it too

Answer (score 0):

The easier way would be to use the STEP option of sliteToggle.

Just update your javascript with the following (change FOOTER_CONTAINER by the appropriate element which should be your footer's wrapper) :

```
$('#footer-expander').click(function(){
    $('#footer-hidden').slideToggle({duration: 'slow', step: function(){
        $(FOOTER_CONTAINER).scrollIntoView(false);
    }, complete: function(){
      goToByScroll('footer-wrapper')
        if($('#footer-expander').html('-')){
            $('#footer-expander').html('+');
        }
        if($('#footer-expander').html('+')){
            $('#footer-expander').html('-');
       }
    }});
});
```

With this, the function

```
$(FOOTER_CONTAINER).scrollIntoView(false);
```

will be called at every step and will scroll your container into view (false aligns it with the bottom).

Comment: Small note which might be important to some people: if your animation is alow (lets say 10sec), the step function gets called allot. Not neccecary a problem, but something to keep in might.